# How can I change visibility of Field Manager in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am Developing app for Blackberry.in button click event i want to hide/invisible verticalFieldManager at run time and show/visible new verticalFieldManager . How i can do this i have'nt any idea. Does any buddy have idea for my issue please send me..
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by replacing the fields

```
screen.replace(oldField, newField);
```